# Recursive method return values in asterisks

Tags: java, recursion, methods, return

I'm trying to create a recursive method that returns a value, and prints the value in my main method. I'm confused on how to return and print in main() a row of X asterisks (**..)
X being a integer on the commandline.
For example the commandline argument is 5.
 
It should output to: *****

My code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] commandlineArguments){
      if(commandlineArguments.length == 0){
         System.out.println("Please enter a least one commandline!");
      }
      else{
         Integer number = new Integer(0); //initialize number
         try{
            Integer x = Integer.parseInt(commandlineArguments[0]);
         }
         catch(NumberFormatException exception){ //NumberFormatException
            System.out.println(exception+" is not a integer!");
            System.exit(1); //end program
         }
         Integer num1 = recursiveMethods.asterisks(number); //A (return address)
         System.out.println(num1);
      }
   }

   public static Integer asterisks(Integer number){
      String asterisks1 = "*";

      for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
         return i;
      }
      return number;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive method have two characteristics:

1. It calls to itself to provide the solution
2. It has a base case that contains where the recursive call must stop.

Your `asterisks` method does not fulfill any of these. Since this looks like homework, I would only provide an explanation about how this method should be, the implementation will be yours:

1. Since your method needs to return asterisks, it would be better returning a `String` instead of an `Integer`. This `String` will contain all the `*`s needed.
2. Define a base case. This can be where `number` have a value of 1.
3. If `number` is greater than 1, then you should return an asterisk and the result of calling to `asterisks` method using the rest of asterisks the whole result needs.

Comment: This is a great answer. I suggest you follow it and if you get stuck re-post what you currently have and what issues you are having instead of just taking one of the other answers. Another way to think of a base case is when you know the answer, typically when it's trivial so no recursion is needed. In this case there are two good base cases, what happens if number is 0? What should your function return? What about if your number is 1? Either would make a good base case for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation Luiggi :)
I was able to complete my method without a hand fed answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
     return i;
  }
```

This loop will only run one time, and it will immediately return i = 0. You don't want that. Make it append a * to your `asterisks1` variable each iteration, then after the loop is finished, return `asterisks1` to the caller and print it.

Also, just FYI, this method is not recursive. A recursive method by definition calls itself at some point.

Answer (score 0):

to do it recursively you must call itself in itself. for example :

```
public static void main(String[] commandlineArguments){
      if(commandlineArguments.length == 0){
         System.out.println("Please enter a least one commandline!");
      }
      else{
         Integer number = new Integer(0); //initialize number
         try{
            Integer x = Integer.parseInt(commandlineArguments[0]);
         }
         catch(NumberFormatException exception){ //NumberFormatException
            System.out.println(exception+" is not a integer!");
            System.exit(1); //end program
         }
         recursiveMethods.asterisks(number); //A (return address)             
      }
   }
   public static void asterisks(Integer number) {
      if(number == 0)
          return;
      else {
          System.out.print("*");
          asterisks(number - 1);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now you solved OP's problem and he/she may not learn anything from this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to call the asterisk function recursively, and return the built up String of asterisks, something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] commandlineArguments) {
    if (commandlineArguments.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a least one commandline!");
    } else {
        Integer number = new Integer(0); // initialize number
        try {
            number = Integer.parseInt(commandlineArguments[0]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) { // NumberFormatException
            System.out.println(exception + " is not a integer!");
            System.exit(1); // end program
        }
        String asterisk = asterisks(number); // A (return address)
        System.out.println(asterisk);
    }
}

public static String asterisks(Integer number) {
    if (number == 0) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return "*" + asterisks(number - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done as,

```
public static String asterisks(int n){
    return (n==1)?"*":asterisks(n-1)+"*";
}
```

Note : return Type is String

**EDIT:** For `n <= 0` it prints nothing

```
public static String asterisks(int n){
    return (n<=0)?"":asterisks(n-1)+"*";
}
```